# convert Json file To C# and stored in database

Tags: c#, json

I want convert JSON file to C# class and stored in database.
My Code

```
string json = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(Path);
```

```html
  {
 "qqq": "xxxx",
 "rrrr": "xxxxx",
 "abc": {
  "abc1": "xxxxx",
  "abc2": "xxxxx",
  "abc3": "xxxxx",
  "abc4": "xxxxx",
  "abc5": "2018-05-28T06:10:00.000"
 },
 "xyx": {
  "xyz1": "xxxxx",
  "xyz2": "xxxxx",
  "xyz3": "xxxxx",
  "xyz4": "xxxxx",
  "xyz5": "2018-05-28T07:30:00.000"
 }
},
{
 "qqq": "xxxxx",
 "rrrr": "xxxxx",
 "abc": {
  "abc1": "xxxxx",
  "abc2": "xxxxx",
  "abc3": "xxxxx",
  "abc4": "xxxxx",
  "abc5": "2018-05-28T06:10:00.000"
 },
 "xyz": {
  "xyz1": "xxxxx",
  "xyz2": "xxxxx",
  "xyz3": "xxxxx",
  "xyz4": "xxxxx",
  "xyz5": "2018-05-28T07:30:00.000",
 }
}
```

```html
public class Rootobject
{
 public string qqq { get; set; }
 public string rrrr { get; set; }
 public Abc abc { get; set; }
 public Xyz xyz { get; set; }
 
}
public class Abc
{
 public string abc1 { get; set; }
 public string abc2 { get; set; }
 public string abc3 { get; set; }
 public string abc4 { get; set; }
 public DateTime abc5 { get; set; }
}
public class Xyz
{
 public string xyz1 { get; set; }
 public string xyz2 { get; set; }
 public string xyz3 { get; set; }
 public string xyz4 { get; set; }
 public DateTime xyz5 { get; set; }
}
```

```
Rootobject ra = new Rootobject();
            ra = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

I have received below error
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'testProject.Form1+Rootobject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JSON provided , there are collection of RootObjects but not one . You have to deserialize into Array of RootObjects .

```
Rootobject[] ra ;    
        ra = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject[]>(json);
```

Also [] are missing in the JSON

Comment: @raj . Thanks . Mark it as answer if you were able to resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

First thing The JSON you gave is not valid.
You can test here [JsonLint](https://jsonlint.com/)
The valid JSON is..

```
[{
    "qqq": "xxxx",
    "rrrr": "xxxxx",
    "abc": {
        "abc1": "xxxxx",
        "abc2": "xxxxx",
        "abc3": "xxxxx",
        "abc4": "xxxxx",
        "abc5": "2018-05-28T06:10:00.000"
    },
    "xyx": {
        "xyz1": "xxxxx",
        "xyz2": "xxxxx",
        "xyz3": "xxxxx",
        "xyz4": "xxxxx",
        "xyz5": "2018-05-28T07:30:00.000"
    }
 }, {
    "qqq": "xxxxx",
    "rrrr": "xxxxx",
    "abc": {
        "abc1": "xxxxx",
        "abc2": "xxxxx",
        "abc3": "xxxxx",
        "abc4": "xxxxx",
        "abc5": "2018-05-28T06:10:00.000"
    },
    "xyz": {
        "xyz1": "xxxxx",
        "xyz2": "xxxxx",
        "xyz3": "xxxxx",
        "xyz4": "xxxxx",
        "xyz5": "2018-05-28T07:30:00.000"
    }
 }]
```

Then Model should be

```
public class Rootobject
    {
        public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public string qqq { get; set; }
        public string rrrr { get; set; }
        public Abc abc { get; set; }
        public Xyx xyx { get; set; }
        public Xyz xyz { get; set; }
    }

    public class Abc
    {
        public string abc1 { get; set; }
        public string abc2 { get; set; }
        public string abc3 { get; set; }
        public string abc4 { get; set; }
        public DateTime abc5 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Xyx
    {
        public string xyz1 { get; set; }
        public string xyz2 { get; set; }
        public string xyz3 { get; set; }
        public string xyz4 { get; set; }
        public DateTime xyz5 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Xyz
    {
        public string xyz1 { get; set; }
        public string xyz2 { get; set; }
        public string xyz3 { get; set; }
        public string xyz4 { get; set; }
        public DateTime xyz5 { get; set; }
    }
```

Now you try, maybe this will fix the issue if not please mention the further detail.

Comment: in addition: to see how your object should be look like in json, you can just create object and serialize it

Comment: There is no need to create RootObject class, the JSON can be deserialized using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject[]>(json); as mentioned in the @Pranith's answer

Comment: Anyway @raj got the solution. Thanks to pranith

Answer (score 0):

It seems your JSON is invalid, and the deserialized item should not be single object it should be list.

JSON

```
[
  {
    "qqq": "xxxx",
    "rrrr": "xxxxx",
    "abc": {
      "abc1": "xxxxx",
      "abc2": "xxxxx",
      "abc3": "xxxxx",
      "abc4": "xxxxx",
      "abc5": "2018-05-28T06:10:00.000"
    },
    "xyx": {
      "xyz1": "xxxxx",
      "xyz2": "xxxxx",
      "xyz3": "xxxxx",
      "xyz4": "xxxxx",
      "xyz5": "2018-05-28T07:30:00.000"
    }
  },
  {
    "qqq": "xxxxx",
    "rrrr": "xxxxx",
    "abc": {
      "abc1": "xxxxx",
      "abc2": "xxxxx",
      "abc3": "xxxxx",
      "abc4": "xxxxx",
      "abc5": "2018-05-28T06:10:00.000"
    },
    "xyz": {
      "xyz1": "xxxxx",
      "xyz2": "xxxxx",
      "xyz3": "xxxxx",
      "xyz4": "xxxxx",
      "xyz5": "2018-05-28T07:30:00.000"
    }
  }
]
```

CODE

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //json url https://api.myjson.com/bins/1dbuse
        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        string json = c.DownloadString("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1dbuse");

        var ra = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rootobject>>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(ra.First().qqq);
    }
}

public class Rootobject
{
    public string qqq { get; set; }
    public string rrrr { get; set; }
    public Abc abc { get; set; }
    public Xyz xyz { get; set; }

}
public class Abc
{
    public string abc1 { get; set; }
    public string abc2 { get; set; }
    public string abc3 { get; set; }
    public string abc4 { get; set; }
    public DateTime abc5 { get; set; }
}
public class Xyz
{
    public string xyz1 { get; set; }
    public string xyz2 { get; set; }
    public string xyz3 { get; set; }
    public string xyz4 { get; set; }
    public DateTime xyz5 { get; set; }
}
```

here's fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AmWnxF